# Prolog Creating a list give me a random | in the list.

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing random problems for practice and I keep running into the same little issue with lists. For some reason I keep getting a pipe symbol at the end of the List when I'm inserting/appending/modifying the List. Example of one such code that does that to me:

```
insertBetween([], E, []).
insertBetween([X], E, X).
insertBetween([X|Xs], E, [X, E | Zs]):- insertBetween(Xs, E, Zs).
```

I try the following command:

```
insertBetween([1,2,3], 0, Res).
```

which return as : Res = [1, 0, 2, 0|3].

Why Am I getting this answer when I'm expected to get Res = [1,0,2,0,3]? Am I doing the base cases wrong? For the last few  weeks, I have come to dislike this Program lang... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @false's answer even if you write:
`insertBetween([X], E, [X]).` instead of `insertBetween([X], E, X).`
you get:

```
?- insertBetween([1,2,3], 0, Res).
Res = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3] ;
Res = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0].
```

That because the second and third rules/clauses can both succeed giving different results ,so you need to make third clause differ from second like:

```
insertBetween([], _, []).
insertBetween([X], _, [X]).
insertBetween([X,Y|Xs], E, [X, E | Zs]):- insertBetween([Y|Xs], E, Zs).
```

This gives:

```
?- insertBetween([1,2,3], 0, Res).
Res = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3] ;
false.
```

Note that the third  clause works if the list has at least two elements but when it has only one then second clause succeeds. Also when you have  for example: `insertBetween([], E, []).` where E is not used it is better replacing it with `insertBetween([], _, []).`

Comment: Hm, That _ also  get rid  of those annoying warning i keep getting. So, when you "don't" use variables in your clauses, we should use _?

Comment: When a variable is not used (sinlgeton variable) which means that you don't care  about it's value and  in this case you use '_' which is anonymous variable and unifies with anything. More specifically in your case : insertBetween([], _, []).  means that if first list is [ ] then whatever middle variable is then third argument should be empty list [ ].

Comment: Ah, Thank for clarifying that.

Comment: glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
insertBetween([X], E, X).
               ^      ^
```

So X is an element of a list and a list.